# Best way to save jpeg from Gstreamer appsinnk

Tags: c, jpeg, gstreamer, mjpeg

I have a USB camera generating MJPEG stream which I am reading by my app. I would like to save the images (a JPEG). I have tried to do so by creating a second pipeline from the app to the image, but I am the first one to admit that I have no idea how to correctly terminate such a pipeline. The implementation crashes the app after average of 3 images taken.
I do not wish to encode a re-decode the image if possible. Is there a different way to save the image than creating the second pipeline/decoding the image?

My current implemenation is:

```
static GstFlowReturn new_sample_jpeg(GstElement * elt, MyStruct *data){

    GstSample *sample;
    GstBuffer *buffer;
    GstMemory *memory;
    GstMapInfo info;
    GstFlowReturn ret = GST_FLOW_OK;
    // get the sample from appsink
    sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample (GST_APP_SINK (elt));
    //if recording, send the sample to recording sink
    if (data->saveVideo) addSampleFromAppsinkVideo(gst_sample_copy(sample));
    buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer (sample);

    if (buffer != NULL){
 memory = gst_buffer_get_memory (buffer, 0);

    if (memory != NULL) {
        //now all data are image data. If image wanted->image save!
        if (data->saveImage) saveSampleFromAppsinkJpeg(gst_sample_copy(sample));
        ...

        gst_memory_unref(memory);
    } else {
        std::cerr << "sample_from_sink(): ERROR memory" << std::endl;
    }
} else {
    std::cerr << "sample_from_sink(): ERROR buffer " << gst_buffer_get_size(buffer) << std::endl;
}
gst_sample_unref (sample);
return ret;
}



int saveSampleFromAppsinkJpeg( GstSample *sample){

//create the pipeline
GstStateChangeReturn ret;

GstElemenent *source = gst_element_factory_make ("appsrc", "appsrc_capture");
GstElemenent *sink = gst_element_factory_make ("multifilesink", "sink_capture");

g_object_set (sink, "location", "some/path.jpg", NULL);

GstElemenent *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline_img");

if (!pipeline || !source || !sink) {
  g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
  return false;
}

GstCaps *caps;
caps = gst_sample_get_caps(sample);

gst_app_src_set_caps(GST_APP_SRC(source), caps);
gst_app_src_set_duration(GST_APP_SRC(source), GST_TIME_AS_MSECONDS(80));
gst_app_src_set_stream_type(GST_APP_SRC(source), GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_STREAM);
gst_app_src_set_latency(GST_APP_SRC(source), -1, 0);

gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, sink, NULL);
gst_caps_unref (caps);
if (gst_element_link_many(source, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
  g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
return -1;
}

ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
  g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return -1;
}

//push the image in the pipeline
GstFlowReturn status = GstFlowReturn::GST_FLOW_OK;
status = gst_app_src_push_sample(GST_APP_SRC(source),sample);
if (status !=  GstFlowReturn::GST_FLOW_OK) g_printerr ("Sample for saving image not pushed: code %d.\n", status);
usleep(500000); // not clean. But how to do this better?
status = gst_app_src_end_of_stream(GST_APP_SRC(source));
if (status !=  GstFlowReturn::GST_FLOW_OK) g_printerr ("EOS for saving image not pushed %d \n", status);
usleep(500000); // not clean. But how to do this better?

//end the pipeline
GstMessage *EndMessage = gst_message_new_eos(&pipeline->object);
gst_bus_post(pipeline->bus, EndMessage);
gst_element_send_event(pipeline, gst_event_new_eos());

/* Free resources */
if (EndMessage != NULL) gst_message_unref (EndMessage);
status = gst_app_src_end_of_stream(GST_APP_SRC(source));

//end the pipeline
usleep(500000); // not clean. But how to do this better?
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
GstState currentState = GST_STATE_READY;
GstClockTime timeout = 50;
uint8_t safetyCounter = 255;
do{
    gst_element_get_state(pipeline, &currentState, NULL,timeout );
    if (safetyCounter-- == 0){ //ok, something is seqiously broken here
        break;
    }
    usleep(10000);
} while (currentState != GST_STATE_NULL);

gst_object_unref (pipeline);
gst_sample_unref(sample);
return 1;
```

}

Comment: Instead of creating a new pipeline and pushing samples via appsrc, why not `tee` your original pipeline using the `tee` element. I think it might be simpler.

Comment: I did try that at some point. I have, however, completely failed at terminating only one branch of the pipeline (saving) in a way, that would allow the main branch (further work on the stream in the app) to continue and to capture again when necessary. Plus I believed that that approach would not allow metadata modification of the saved image in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I am just using the uvc library (https://github.com/libuvc/libuvc) to decode the mjpeg into rgb, and then I encode it as jpeg with jpeglib. Pretty wastefull, but working.